# If / Else para defenir environment variables no Travis

Tags: github, travis-ci

Estou a usar o Travis para testes em javascript (Grunt/Karma) e defino algumas variáveis no ficheiro `.travis.yml` para correr uma matriz de testes. O que me está a faltar é um meio de defenir variáveis usando um if/else.

Procuro algo parecido com esta lógica:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.11
env:
  matrix:
    if ($TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == 'false') {
      - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='default'
      - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='nocompat'
      - BROWSER='firefox_linux'   BUILD='default'
      - BROWSER='firefox_linux'   BUILD='nocompat'
   }
   else {
     - BROWSER='phantomjs'    BUILD='default'
   }
```

Uso a variável do travis `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` para controlar se o teste é despoletado por um Pull Request no GitHub ou não. No caso de ser um Pull Request quero testar o código só com o PhantomJS.

Usando as variáveis em cima sem o If/Else funciona, mas queria evitar usar testes em browsers porque esses são feitos no SauceLabs e como a password está enciptada no fiheiro `.yml` o teste falha se o Pull Request fôr de outro repositório no GitHub por questões de segurança.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto aparentemente não é possivel no Travis. A solução que encontrei foi usar essa variàvel que o travis dá (`$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`) e usá-la dentro do meu `gruntfile` onde é disponibilizada pelo grunt em `process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`.

Essa variável do Travis é uma string, mesmo quando passa `false`, daí eu usar `pullRequest != 'false'`.

```
var pullRequest = process.env.TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST;
var tasks = ['clean', 'packager:all', 'packager:specs'];
tasks =  pullRequest != 'false' ? tasks.concat('karma:continuous') : tasks.concat('karma:sauceTask');

grunt.registerTask('default:travis', tasks);
```